# juju wordpress deploy using lxc

Tags: juju, wordpress, lxc

Since I use LXC alot, I've been waiting for the new go version of juju to support LXC again for sometime now!
I just reinstalled juju .7
I am running Ubuntu 13.04

my environment.yaml has - type: local

I followed this example from juju .6:
https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/getting-started.html

just to see if JuJu would deploy mysql and wordpress to the lxc containers

Both **mysql and wordpress successfully deployed and started**..

I did expose wordpress.

```
$ juju status  
machines:   
  0:  
    agent-state: running  
    dns-name: localhost  
    instance-id: local  
    instance-state: running  
services:  
  mysql:  
    charm: cs:precise/mysql-21  
    relations:  
      cluster:  
      - mysql  
      db:  
      - wordpress  
    units:  
      mysql/0:  
        agent-state: started  
        machine: 0  
        public-address: 10.0.3.227  
  wordpress:  
    charm: cs:precise/wordpress-15  
    exposed: true  
    relations:  
      db:  
      - mysql  
      loadbalancer:  
      - wordpress  
    units:  
      wordpress/0:  
        agent-state: started  
        machine: 0  
        open-ports: []  
        public-address: 10.0.3.123  
        relation-errors:  
          db:  
          - mysql  
2013-06-02 21:27:49,612 INFO 'status' command finished successfully
```

I can ping the WordPress IP 10.0.3.123 from the host.

But WordPress is not accessible from host via browser - I assume because WordPress still reports open-ports: []

but this is all on local machine and I guess I'm asking is what should I have to do to open up port 80 to the JuJu WordPress container.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because the default networking for LXC does not bridge to the host. So, all those instances can see each other, but you can't directly see them from the host.
To test this you could try and

```
juju ssh wordpress/0
```

and see if you get connectivity locally.
We will be documenting an LXC network setup specifically for Juju, but for now there are general Ubuntu docs which cover this: [Ubuntu Server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, did you do `juju expose wordpress`?

If you did, you can try and access `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, to see whether it reports some file missing. You can also try `netstat -i` or `lsof`, to see whether there is any port open.

HTTP should be, for instance. Theoretically, you shouldn't have to do anything, it's worked for me out of the box.